# How to set 2 dim Array by input string without blank?

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    String[][] s = new String[size][size];

    for (int row = 0; row < s.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < s[row].length; col++) {
            s[row][col] = sc.next();
        }
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < s.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < s[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.print(s[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Now when i input 3, then input array value:

```
3
a b c
a b c
a b c
```

The output like this:

```
a b c
a b c
a b c
```

So I want to know how can i change the code to get same output when I input like this:

```
3
abc
abc
abc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
int size = sc.nextInt();
String[][] s = new String[size][];

for (int row = 0; row < s.length; row++) {
    s[row] = sc.next().split("");
}
for (int row = 0; row < s.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < s[row].length; col++) {
        System.out.print(s[row][col] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to copy each row item to the matrix.  Just assign the output of split to `s[row]`.  This also means you can initialize `s` as `String[][]  s = new String[size][];`

Answer (score 0):

The java.util.Scanner.next() method finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceeded and followed by input **that matches the delimiter pattern**. So, scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default **matches whitespace**.
You must use some kind of delimiter. For example, you can set delimiter to be ','

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.useDelimiter(",");
```

Then your input should be like this :

```
3,
a,b,c,
a,b,c,
a,b,c,
```

And Your output would be :

```
a b c 

a b c 

a b c
```

In your case, if you want to take input like this:

```
3
abc
abc
abc
```

and then take characters one by one, you can't do it like that, beacause you must specify some delimiter, and as I said, if you don't the default delimiter will be taken.

However, you can write a workaround code, something like this :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.useDelimiter("\\n");

        int size = sc.nextInt();
        String[][] s = new String[size][size];

        for (int row = 0; row < s.length; row++) {
            String input = sc.next();
            for (int col = 0; col < s[row].length; col++) {

                    s[row][col] = String.valueOf(input.toCharArray()[col]);
            }
        }


        for (int row = 0; row < s.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < s[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(s[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Then You pass your input like this:

```
3
abc
abc
abc
```

And you should see the following output:

```
a b c 
a b c 
a b c
```

Answer (score 0):

Imho, this is the easiest way.  It also allows for each row to be a different length if you want.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int size = sc.nextInt();
// clear the previous new line
sc.nextLine();
//initialize the number of rows.
String[][] s = new String[size][];

// enter the rows
for (int rows = 0; rows < size; rows++) {
    String row = sc.nextLine();
    // split between each character
    s[rows] = row.split("");
}

//print the matrix
for (String[] row : s) {
    System.out.println(String.join(" ",row));
}
```

For input

```
3
abc
def
ghi
```

Prints

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```